# It can't calculate count(*) in a query onto DB2 database

Tags: db2

I want to do a count(*) of the number of a rows fom a DB2 database.
The basic query is the following:

```
select 
SUBSTR("Request_Detail",LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail")+1,LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail",LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail")+1)-LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail"))

 from "Request_Analisys"

 WHERE
 "Sample_Date_and_Time">=1200323230000000 and "Sample_Date_and_Time"<1200332300000000
 and "Request_Detail" <> '[Summary]'
 and "Request_Detail" not like 'WS:%'
```

Now I'd like to do a count(*) of the resulting rows, but if I do a query like this:

```
select 
count(*),
SUBSTR("Request_Detail",LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail")+1,LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail",LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail")+1)-LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail"))

 from "Request_Analisys"

 WHERE
 "Sample_Date_and_Time">=1200323230000000 and "Sample_Date_and_Time"<1200332300000000
 and "Request_Detail" <> '[Summary]'
 and "Request_Detail" not like 'WS:%'
```

It gives the error:

18:51:58  FAILED  [SELECT - 0 rows, 0.032 secs]  1) [Code: -119, SQL State: 42803]  An expression starting with "Request_Detail" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.. SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, DRIVER=4.22.29
2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-119", SQLSTATE "42803" and message tokens "Request_Detail".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.22.29

How could I do to get the count of the rows?

Comment: `select count(*) from (your-basic-query)`. If it’s not you want, then provide a sample of the result set returned by your basic query and the result you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Which `Request_Detail` line's substr would you think it shows after the count?
If you count the lines, the result set will be a single line, and using any columns in it makes no sense.

If you want multiple lines, with a count for each found substr, you need to `GROUP BY` this substr.

Comment: True, but if I add the group by clause I get the following error: [Code: -138, SQL State: 22011]  The statement was not executed because a numeric argument of a scalar function is out of range.. SQLCODE=-138, SQLSTATE=22011, DRIVER=4.22.29

Answer (score 0):

This may work...

```
select 
count(
SUBSTR("Request_Detail"
       ,LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail")+1
       ,LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail",LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail")+1)
          -LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail")))
)
 from "Request_Analisys"
 WHERE
 "Sample_Date_and_Time">=1200323230000000 and "Sample_Date_and_Time"<1200332300000000
 and "Request_Detail" <> '[Summary]'
 and "Request_Detail" not like 'WS:%'
```

But if not this should..

```
with cte as (
select 
SUBSTR("Request_Detail"
       ,LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail")+1
       ,LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail",LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail")+1)
          -LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail"))) as mydetail
 from "Request_Analisys"
 WHERE
 "Sample_Date_and_Time">=1200323230000000 and "Sample_Date_and_Time"<1200332300000000
 and "Request_Detail" <> '[Summary]'
 and "Request_Detail" not like 'WS:%'
)
select count(*) from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `REGEXP_EXTRACT` to pick what you want out of your "Request_Detail" column. This is more flexable than using `SUBSTR` and `LOCATE`, and will avoid the `statement was not executed because a numeric argument of a scalar function is out of range..` error

e.g

```
select
    REGEXP_EXTRACT("Request_Detail",'.*/(.+/)',1,1,'',1)
,   SUBSTR("Request_Detail",LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail")+1,LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail",LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail")+1)-LOCATE('/',"Request_Detail"))
FROM TABLE(VALUES('aaaa/bbbb/ccc')) AS T("Request_Detail")
```

returns

```
1     |2    
------|-----
bbbb/ |bbbb/
```

so, you could then do this

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
,   REGEXP_EXTRACT("Request_Detail",'.*/(.+/)',1,1,'',1)
FROM
     "Request_Analisys"
GROUP BY
    REGEXP_EXTRACT("Request_Detail",'.*/(.+/)',1,1,'',1)
```

for example